# Vaadin measure render time

Tags: java, rendering, vaadin, vaadin7, measure

first of all, I'm using Vaadin 7 and Eclipse Mars.

I want to program a samll performance test and here is my Problem:

I've a list and a button. After the button has clicked, 1000 items are added and displayed in the list. Now I want to see the time it took to render the items in ms. So I'm saving the time after clicking the button and after adding all the items to the list and substract them. The time needed is now displayed in the button but always around 2 ms and 10 ms..this cannot be? How can I measure the actual time?

tl;dr: 
How can I properly measure the render time needed for a 1000 item list.

This happens after clicking the button:

```
public void List(ListSelect select, Button button){
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        select.setRows(1000);

        select.addItems( "item1", "item2", "item1000");

        long millis2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        button.setCaption(millis2 - millis +" ms");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendering time can be seen with the Vaadin Debug Window. Append `?debug` to the application root (`app/?debug#!home`). Then you can see the debug window in the lower right corner. The first symbol on the menu shows the log. The line `Processing time was ...ms` shows the rendering time of your browser. More detailed, it's the time the browser needs to process the JSON response that is rendered to HTML.

Comment: Works! But is it possible to get/save the Processing Time in a variable?

Comment: I just noticed, that the rendering is much slower with `?debug`. Is there a solution/workaround?

Comment: An alternative would be to use for example Chrome's Developer Tools. In the console you would also see the `Processing time was ...` as an entry without using Vaadin's debug window.

Comment: I think for storing the processing time in a variable, that you could send back to the server, you would need to write a client side extension.